# How to tell if Windows Taskbar's "autohide" is enabled?

Tags: delphi, winapi, taskbar, windows-explorer

How can I tell via a Delphi program if the Windows Explorer Taskbar is set to Autohide?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows XP and higher, you can call [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787947(VS.85).aspx) API with `ABM_GETSTATE` message.

Syntax:

```
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETSTATE, pabd);
```

`pabd` is a pointer to `APPBARDATA` struct.
header file is: shellapi.h.

If you want to get state of taskbar, use `ABM_GETSTATE` message.
you can call this api in delphi.

Answer (score 11):

What is is that you *really* want to find out? Is it because you want to know the area of the screen that is useable?

If so, then I believe you can use the Screen.WorkAreaRect to determine the available screen area, where all (permanent) tool bars etc. are excluded.

Comment: If the taskbar is in Autohide mode, then the space the taskbar uses will be included in the working area, even if the taskbar is currently in the visible position.

Comment: Yes - hence my "(permanent)" comment. When the task bar is in AutoHide mode, it is not a permanent task bar, and thus the screen space available includes the area that the task bar will cover when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Use Win32 shell apis (IsTBAutohide and others)
See Google Groups for undocumented apis.
Never read registry (ans stop removing right answers, it's stupid...)

Answer (score -2):

U have to deal with windows registry because this information is keept in there. Value indicating "autoohide" is written(read) only while user logon /logout ont with his account

Registry key responsible for storing this information is located in
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2**
The only thing in there is **settings** and it is a 9th hex value
for "autohide on" this value is **03** for "autohide off" it is **02**

Comment: That's a hack. One should ALWAYS use an API rather than access to undocumented registry info.